# rails whenever running cronjob in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I've got lots of cronjobs, those work fine when I run them in development environemet ... now I have test server and set them to environmen test ...

Now they don't work ... got everytime this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'xyz_production'
```

schedule.rb looks like this:

```
every 13.minutes do
  rake "crons:generate", :environment => :test
end
```

and the cron task looks like this:

```
desc "Generate"
  task(:generate => :environment) do
```

whats the problem here?

in database yml I have defined development / test / production / staging and everywhere the correct credentials are set.

I run the application in test environment and it works fine. only the cronjob does not what he should do

Comment: does the database.yml specify a database connection available in the server environment?

Comment: yeah I have set test: in database.yml added the infos above

Comment: please add `crontab -l` output, and what is your whenever's gem version